# Form validation

Tags: html, validation

I am new in web development. I have a form and want to set validation:

1. Can not be empty and it should print out underneath or same page.
2. LastName value  of input needs to be printed in reverse.
3. In select option when user selected favorite day of week print the date of next 6 occurrences of this day.

HTML

```
    <form role="form">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fName">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fName" placeholder="First Name">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lName" placeholder="Last Name">
                                      </div>
<div class="form-group">
                                    <select id="select" placeholder="Favorite day of the week"> 
                         <option selected="selected" ></option>
                         <option value="abc">Monday</option>
                         <option value="def">Tuesday</option>
                         <option value="hij">Wednesday</option> 
                         <option value="hij">Thursday</option>
                         <option value="hij">Friday</option>
                         <option value="hij">Saturday</option>
                         <option value="hij">Sunday</option>
                        </select>
                                  </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code a little better and explain exactly what's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very helpful if you explain your issues further in detail, it's a bit hard to answer everything in this way. As for general validation you can basically go ahead and google a search for a guide.

Comment: Thanks i will check google guide for basic form validation,Its form validation when user submit with empty field in form there should be alert can not submit empty...